# How can I force kramdown (or Nanoc) to generate <br> instead of <br /> for line breaks?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, markdown, kramdown, nanoc

I’m using [kramdown](https://kramdown.gettalong.org) with static site generator [Nanoc](https://nanoc.app) to generate HTML from Markdown.

By default, kramdown is generating Markdown double-spaces as XHTML-friendly `<br />` instead of HTML5's `<br>`, so the HTML5 validator is “informing” about this:

> Info: Trailing slash on void elements has no effect and interacts badly with unquoted attribute values.
> From line … (etc)
> text_here.`<br />`

Is there a kramdown or Nanoc option/command to force `<br>` instead of `<br />` for line breaks indicated by double-spaces at a line end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit the html.rb file in (…)/gems/kramdown/

I found the location of the relevant code on line 267 of the [HTML converter](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/rdoc/Kramdown/Converter/Html.html#method-i-convert_br) in:

"/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/kramdown-2.4.0/lib/kramdown/converter/html.rb" (my Ruby is Homebrew-installed)

and (sudo) edited `<br />` to `<br>` with [Micro](https://micro-editor.github.io) (command-line editor: `brew install micro`) to preserve the file’s permissions and ownership.

Then recompiled a Markdown file with double-space line breaks and am now seeing `<br>` instead of `<br />`. Also did the same for other self-closing HTML5 tags (`img` and `hr`) as well as the places where kramdown parses self-closing tags in raw HTML inside Markdown files - just replaced  `/>` with `>`, carefully, and manually. Now getting nice HTML5 output that the validator likes.

You can see the HTML converter on the [kramdown GitHub repo](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/blob/master/lib/kramdown/converter/html.rb).

However, I presume any update to the kramdown gem will overwrite it - so if anyone knows how to make this change permanent for a local kramdown gem, advice is welcome. See [this post on the kramdown Google group](https://groups.google.com/g/kramdown-users/c/m8I_hHFALk0)